La clase active no funciona con las url de Django
Tengo un side menú sencillo, y lo único que quiero hacer es usar la clase active para que cuando yo seleccione una parte del side menú esta se muestre como de un color diferente y de que esta seleccionada.
Lo que pasa es que sí se hace esto pero como estoy usando Django para manejar mi sistema, en las etiquetas  pongo una url para redirigirme a otra pagina de mi sistema
 <li class="navbar-item">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined">Person</span>
            <a  class="nav-link nav-a" href="{% url 'clientes' %}" id="mostrarTabla">Gestion de Clientes</a>
  </li>

y ahí es cuando me deja de funcionar el active, ya no se queda seleccionado y es como si la clase active no estuviera. Ya intente con buttons, con ajax, javascript y nada, siempre es el mismo problema de las url y no se como solucionarlo porque necesito los dos funcionamientos.
Este es el scrip que estoy usando para quitar y poner el active
<script>
      $('li').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    })
  </script>

También estoy usando boostrap, pero no para esa clase en específico.
En Django estoy manejando las plantillas, y el side menu es mi plantilla principal y ahí yo inserto el contenido que quiero mostrar
